The \w in PS1 cannot deal as string?
I want a color splited path in PS1. I write this function in .bashrc.

    colorize_dir_path() {
        #local path=$(echo "$PWD" | perl -pe "s|$HOME|~|")
        #local path="~/project/at-gui/src"
        local path=$1
        local colored_path=""
        local color_array=(27 130 28 133)
        local index=0
        IFS='/' read -ra ADDR <<< $path
        for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
            if [ "$i" != "" ]; then
                local color=${color_array[$index]}
                ((index=(index+1)%${#color_array[@]}))
                colored_path+="\e[48;5;${color}m $i "
            fi
        done
        echo -e "\e[37m${colored_path}➽\e[0m"   #白色前景
    }

and set PS1.
PS1="$psc1 \D{%F %A %T} $pgap$(colorize_dir_path "\w")\n$psch "
#PS1="$psc1 \D{%F %A %T} $pgap$(colorize_dir_path "$PWD")\n$psch "
#PS1="$psc1 \D{%F %A %T} $pgap$(colorize_dir_path "$(pwd)")\n$psch "
#PS1="$psc1 \D{%F %A %T} $pgap$(bash ~/bin/ps1.bash "\w")\n$psch "

But the \w can not split into the ADDR array, I only got the entire path. seems it is not a string. How to solve this? pls help.


a) Your parameters are expanded and your command substituted at the time of variable definition, not when PS1 is rendered. You want to use single quotes instead: PS1='…'. b) quote your parameters when expanding c) have you run your script through shellcheck.net already?

You set IFS to /, but the string does not contain a slash. What kind of "splitting" would you have expected?

Aside: Why are you declaring all your other variables local but not ADDR or i?

Separately, echo -e is bad form; printf is more reliable since it lets you control which strings are and are not interpolated. (printf '%b%s%b' '\e[37m' "$colored_path" '➽\e[0m' for example will treat the escape sequences as such because %b instructs it to interpolate, but without changing your path if it contains literal backslashes or such, because %s treats things exactly as they already are).

PS1="$psc1 \D{%F %A %T} $pgap$(colorize_dir_path "\w")\n$psch "

Expands all parameters at assignment time, including the command substitution. This means that PS1 is assigned a constant value and \w does not have special meaning outside of PS1; it is only expanded by your shell when rendering the prompt string.
Try this instead to make the command substitution only be expanded when your prompt string is rendered (note the single quotes):
PS1="$psc1 \D{%F %A %T} $pgap"'$(colorize_dir_path "\w")'"\n$psch "

The time of evaluation/expansion is easy to verify yourself:
PS1="$(date):\w\$ "
echo "$PS1" # prints: Fr 28 Jun 2024 11:40:44 CEST:\w$

and the time displayed in your prompt is constant and never changes. Compare to:
PS1='$(date):\w\$ '
echo "$PS1" # prints: $(date):\w\$ 

and every time your prompt string is rendered, it will be evaluated and the current date and time printed next to your current working directory.
A similar test:
PS1="$(echo '\w'>&2)\$ "

will print \w to stderr exactly once when assigning the variable. However
PS1='$(echo "\w">&2)\$ '

prints the path of your current working directory to stderr every time your prompt is rendered.

Thanks. PS1='$(colorize_dir_path "\w")' really works. PS1="$(colorize_dir_path "\w")" not work. I read your explain, but still mess up. :(

I saw your comment above. That means I can not let the function $(colorize_dir_path "\w") been expanded till when PS1 is running each time? Keep this part as a whole string, partly understand. Thanks.

The most strange thing is if I use double quote, the function colorize_dir_path is also work, the $path is current path, BUT the ADDR  only had one element.

@eexpress because if invoked outside of prompt rendering, the argument is passed the literal string \w and not the resolved path.
